# Master-Slave non-blocking listener

Tags: c, mpi, nonblocking, master-slave

Currently I'm trying to create a master-slave program with a "listener" loop where the master waits for a message from slaves to make a decision from there. But, despite using non-blocking MPI routines, I am experiencing an error. Do I need to use some blocking routine?

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // Variable Declarations
  int rank, size;
  MPI_Request *requestList,requestNull;
  MPI_Status  status;
  // Start MPI
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  if( rank == 0 )
  {
    // Process Zero
    int   dataOut=13, pr;
    float dataIn = -1;
    requestList =(MPI_Request*)malloc((size-1)*sizeof(MPI_Request));

    while(1){
      dataIn = -1;
      // We do NOT  need to wait for the MPI_ Isend(s), it is the job of the receiver  processes.
      for(pr=1;pr<size;pr++)
      {
        MPI_Irecv(&dataIn,1,MPI_FLOAT,pr,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&(requestList[pr-1]));
      }
      if((dataIn > 1.5)){
        printf("From the process: %f\n", dataIn);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Receiver Process
    float message;
    int index;
    //MPI_Request request;
    MPI_Status  status;

    while(1){
      message = random()/(double)1147483648;
      // Send the message back to the process zero
      MPI_Isend(&message,1,MPI_FLOAT,0,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD, &requestNull);

      if(message > 1.5)
      break;
    }
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you're never waiting for your MPI calls to complete.

The way non-blocking calls work in MPI is that when you issue a non-blocking call (like `MPI_IRECV`), the last input parameter is an `MPI_REQUEST` object. When the initialization call (`MPI_IRECV`) is done, that request object contains the information for the non-blocking call. However, that call isn't done yet and you have no guarantee that the call is done until you use a completion call (`MPI_WAIT`/`MPI_TEST`/and friends) on the request.

In your case, you probably are using the non-blocking calls unnecessarily since you rely on the information received during the `MPI_IRECV` call in the next line. You should probably just substitute your non-blocking call for a blocking `MPI_RECV` call and use `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` so you don't have to post a separate receive call for each rank in the communicator. Alternatively, you can use `MPI_WAITANY` to complete your non-blocking calls, but then you'll need to worry about cleaning up all of the extra operations when you finish.